# ¿Cómo colocar una restricción en el model para evitar que pueda ser eliminado si tiene datos relacionados?

Tags: cakephp

¿Cómo colocar una restricción en el model para evitar que pueda ser eliminado si tiene datos relacionados en cakephp?

ya usé:

```
 ->setCascadeCallbacks(false)
->setDependent(false)
```

y no ha funcionado.